# Pre-process node type for each node and print within region.html.twig template

Tags: drupal, theming

I'm trying to figure out how I can check the node type/content type for each node using pre-process and print it on a region template `(region.html.twig)`

It seems to be returning `NULL`

```
function iom_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
    $node = $variables["node"];
    $variables['content_type'] = load($node->getType())->label();
}
```

`{{ content_type }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
function iom_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables["node"];
  $variables['content_type'] = $node->bundle();
}
```

$node->getType() should work, too.

For region.html.twig:

```
function iom_preprocess_region(&$variables) {
  if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
    $variables['content_type'] = $node->bundle();
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried that before but I can't seem to print it within the `region.html.twig` template, but it works if placed it within the `node.html.twig`

Comment: Right, my bad.  Then you'll want to use iom_preprocess_region().  Then, in there, check for a node (using route params?) and add the variable.